# Obj-C: Usage of callbacks

Tags: objective-c, callback

There is a method in the Google Maps SDK that uses callbacks like these, I guess it´s blocks? anyways I have never used these before. I just want to see if the method requestPanoramaNearCoordinate returns a valid Panorama near the coordinate i give it. How do i use the callback to see what the callback returns? If it returns a valid Panorama at the coordinate I want to return it - if not I´ll recursively call the method until a valid location is found

```
- (void) requestPanoramaNearCoordinate: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
                              callback: (GMSPanoramaCallback)callback
```

> Retrieves information about a panorama near the given coordinate. This
>   is an asynchronous request, callback will be called with the result.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D ranLatLng = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(ranLatitude,  ranLongitude);

if ([panoService requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:ranLatLng callback:<#^(GMSPanorama *panorama, NSError *error)callback#>)
```

Comment: I clarified the problem

Comment: No. It's still unclear. Do you mean to get the function that the callback is being "called back" from?

Comment: I need to check if what it returns is a valid Panorama image, if it´s not I think it just returns nil - and in that case I want to recursively call the function until a valid panorama is found

Answer (score 1):

It's a block.  You make the api call like this:

```
[aPanoramaService requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:aCoordiante callback:^(GMSPanorama *panorama, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"the service returned a panorama=%@ and an error=%@", panorama, error);
}];
```

One way to do the recursion is to build a method with a similar signature to the google method.  An important point is to find a way for the recursion to stop, possibly because you get tired of searching.

```
- (void)findPanoramaAtLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location withCompletion:(void (^)(GMSPanorama *, NSError *))completion {

    [self.panoramaService requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:location callback:^(GMSPanorama *panorama, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            completion(nil, error);
        } else if (panorama) {
            completion(panorama, nil);
        } else {

            if (/* should we continue searching? */) {

                // compute a new location to try
                double latitude = // compute new latitude
                double longitude = // compute new longitude
                CLLocationCoordinate2D newLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

                [self findPanoramaAtLocation:newLocation withCompletion:completion];

            } else {
                // no panorama and no error means we gave up
                completion(nil, nil);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

This will run, calling the "callback" (it's a block) when either a panorama location is found, when an error occurs, or when your logic determines that it ought to stop searching.

Answer (score 1):

The `panorama` parameter contains the `GMSPanorama` object that the request found for you. It doesn't seem to be documented very clearly, but the usual pattern in Cocoa is that if nothing appropriate was found, the result will be `nil`, and the `NSError` object will give you a little information about why. As for re-making the request, that would look something like this I guess:

```
// Necessary if GMSPanoService is ill-behaved and keeps the Block
// around after calling it.
__weak GMSPanoramaService weak_panoService = panoService;

__block GMSPanoramaCallback cb;
cb = [^(GMSPanorama *panorama, NSError *error){
    if( !panorama ){
        // Do something with error if desired
        CLLocationCoordinate2D newLatLng = /* Calc new coordinates somehow */; 
        [/*weak_*/panoService requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:newLatLng 
                                          callback:cb];
    }
    else {
        // Got a panorama, do something with it
        cb = nil;    // Release Block
    }
} copy];

[panoService requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:ranLatLng 
                                  callback:cb];
```

Comment: I think that might generate a retain cycle on panoService.

Comment: The retain cycle on the Block itself is the problematic one, actually. I didn't do this right, hang on.

Comment: Yes, that fixes the panoService retain cycle.  I think the more correct idiom is __unsafe_unreatined.

Comment: If `GMSPanoramaService` is creating a retain cycle because it's referenced in the Block, then I would argue that it contains a bug. It should be releasing the callback as soon as it has been called, which will break the cycle.

Comment: I think the cycle appears if GMSPanoramaService copies the block (which it probably does legitimately).  That block retains objects to which it refers.  If the block refers directly to the panoService you get a retain cycle on the panoService->block->panoService.  But you fixed it by referring to an unretained copy in the block.

Comment: Yes, that's legitimate, but this is only a problem if the `GMSPanoramaService` is waiting until its `dealloc` to release the copy of the Block, which it _shouldn't_ do.

Comment: Yes.  Good point.  My block containing code doesn't do that.  I should do a pass thru my stuff looking for blocks to nil out after invocation.